# Infer object's values types using Generic

Tags: typescript

I've been stuck on this for a while without being able to find an elegant solution.

I have a Enum:

```js
export enum Enum {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}
```

Then an object that uses said Enum, the structure is relatively known, as it's value will always be a function which will return a string, but the unknown thing is that the function may take any amount of args:

```js
import { A, B, C } from '../enums/';

export const obj = {
    [A]: () => 'example 1',
    [B]: (arg1: string) => 'example 2, arg1: %s',
    [C]: (nr: string, arg2: string) => 'example %s %s',
}
```

Last part of the structure is a function, which makes use of `obj` to retrieve certain strings based on it's args:

```js
const fct = <E extends Enum>(
    code: E,
    ...args: Parameters<(typeof obj)[E]>
) => {
    ...
}
```

Everything works, but it is not type-safe, as I require every Enum value to be assigned to a value inside of `obj`.

If I were to create a basic type, `Parameter` would not display the proper arguments of the function:

```js
type ObjectType = { [key in Enum]: (...args: any[]) => string }
Parameters<(typeof obj)[A]> // -> (...args: any[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constrain the type of `obj` to only allow keys of `Enum` and values of "functions that return `string`" using the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) (see also the type utility [`Record<Keys, Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)), and you can [constrain the generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `E` in the function `fct` by the actual keys of `obj` rather than any `Enum` (which might or might not be present as a key) like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQUoEEA0KoCEuoGEsBfJJAYwHsQBnAFykoCMArKAXimVQG05IAdGgC6ALigAKAJQcAfFADkwAB4BDCAAcANsCgBGBfih94AnGMmqATgHM94+lYCWIGzPbylazTqgAmDChrO3EAUhpDbBNBAgsJECsHOmdXQOC-JJS3OUUVdW1dcKhwyOIoGlU6JxoAMydgGigAJWAqKwATAB5+CECJAQHgmnFVEABPHmF3eUcXG1kAbjIqWgYa8gZObqgVOlB2xoBrYDHKGqg6MY1gM8ZWWQlsKnbgcRgjAYEh8QAFa3VgHsrDROhJLtdbswWFI+MJZEhplxiEskOs6BIekIpAsoAB6XFQADyh1RGwxpkwUAARDVKJQqdi8QSYFYrJQrJIVNcNsB2lIyGjyYI8NTafTGfiiSTBZicBLmaz2ZzlNy9nyyKT0ZiiKK6VTAlSmNYGTjJcTNUKIAIdTS9fLYIqORIua01fyZaYCPaWWynS6eeqkJLAGQEgPIAiQQA)

```ts
enum Enum {
  A,
  B,
  C,
}

const obj = {
  [Enum.A]: () => 'example 1',
  [Enum.B]: (arg1: string) => 'example 2, arg1: %s',
  [Enum.C]: (nr: string, arg2: string) => 'example %s %s',
} satisfies Record<Enum, (...args: any[]) => string>;

const fct = <E extends keyof typeof obj>(
  code: E,
  ...args: Parameters<(typeof obj)[E]>
) => {};

fct(Enum.A); // Ok
fct(Enum.A, "foo"); /* Error (expected)
            ~~~~~
Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.(2554) */

fct(Enum.B, "foo"); // Ok
fct(Enum.B); /* Error (expected)
~~~~~~~~~~~
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.(2554) */


fct(Enum.C, "foo", "bar"); // Ok
fct(Enum.C, "foo"); /* Error (expected)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expected 3 arguments, but got 2.(2554) */

fct(Enum.C); /* Error (expected)
~~~~~~~~~~~
Expected 3 arguments, but got 1.(2554) */

// …etc.
```